# Python Azure Data Factory Update Pipeline

Tags: python, azure, azure-data-factory

I want to use Python to add an activity to a pipeline in Azure Data Factory. With the following code I am replacing the actual activity but not adding a new one:

```py
p_name = 'test'
act_name = 'Wait4'

Wait_activity = WaitActivity(name=act_name,wait_time_in_seconds=5)


p_obj = PipelineResource(activities=[Wait_activity])
p = adf_client.pipelines.create_or_update(rg_name, df_name, p_name, p_obj)
```

This is the pipeline before running the code :
[image]

After running the code:

[image]

Expected :

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Researched the statements in source code:

[image]

So when you update the pipeline, the `activities` property should be the list of activities in pipeline, not single one.

For example:

```
wait_activity = WaitActivity(name="waittest", type="Wait", wait_time_in_seconds=100, )
ActivityDependency = [{"activity":"waittest","dependencyConditions":["Succeeded"]}]
wait_activity1 = WaitActivity(name="waittest1", type="Wait", wait_time_in_seconds=100,depends_on=ActivityDependency)


p_name = 'testforadf'
p_obj = PipelineResource(
        activities=[wait_activity, wait_activity1])
p = adf_client.pipelines.create_or_update(rg_name, df_name, p_name, p_obj)
```

Please note two lines:

```
activities=[wait_activity, wait_activity1])
```

This property should contains all of your activities.

```
ActivityDependency = [{"activity":"waittest","dependencyConditions":["Succeeded"]}]
```

This is the dependency conditions between your activities.

My output:

[image]

Any concern, please let me know.

---

Well,please see my sample code:

**The premise is that I already have the above two wait activities**

```
adftest = adf_client.pipelines.get(rg_name,df_name,p_name)
print(adftest)
for activity in adftest.activities :
    print(activity.name)
    print(activity.type)
```

Then output is :

```
{'additional_properties': None, 'id': '/subscriptions/b83c1ed3-c5b6-44fb-b5ba-2b83a074c23f/resourceGroups/v-jugong-ChinaCXPTeam/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/jaygongadf/pipelines/testforadf', 'name': 'testforadf', 'type': 'Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/pipelines', 'etag': 'ed006cf3-0000-0800-0000-5da970600000', 'description': None, 'activities': [<azure.mgmt.datafactory.models.wait_activity_py3.WaitActivity object at 0x000001C05FEDE0F0>, <azure.mgmt.datafactory.models.wait_activity_py3.WaitActivity object at 0x000001C05FED6DA0>], 'parameters': None, 'variables': None, 'concurrency': None, 'annotations': None, 'folder': None}
waittest
Wait
waittest1
Wait
```

Then you could see the objects in above `activities` property. Besides,you could see their types:  `'activities': [<azure.mgmt.datafactory.models.wait_activity_py3.WaitActivity object at 0x000001C05FEDE0F0>, <azure.mgmt.datafactory.models.wait_activity_py3.WaitActivity object at 0x000001C05FED6DA0>]`

They are WaitActivity type, so you could view their loop the activity to get every item in it using :

```
for activity in adftest.activities :
        print(activity.name)
        print(activity.type)
```

You could view what properties the WaitActivity type contains, like`name`,`type` in source code statements.(For me, i used Pycharm to test code,the IDE could detect source code directly)

[image]

Then if you want to add one more activity,for example, one more WaitActivity:

```
wait_activity2 = WaitActivity(name="waittest2", type="Wait", wait_time_in_seconds=100, )
adftest.activities.append(wait_activity2)
p = adf_client.pipelines.create_or_update(rg_name, df_name, p_name, adftest)
```

Please see above code, i created a new WaitActivity named `wait_activity2` ,then append it into `activities` array. Then update the pipeline as normal, you will find the new activity :

[image]

Comment: It is not exactly what I am looking for.
Let say that I have a Pipeline that already exist with several **activities** and I want to add an **activity** to this Pipeline with Python.
I don't want to recreate the entire pipeline.
So with your solution, if I am right, you are suggesting me to get all the current **activities** of the pipeline and recreate the entire pipeline.
So is there a way to get the list of **activities** with all the property of a Pipeline ?

Comment: Firstly,i have to say that sdk only provides `create_or_update` method, no any methods like  `append` or `add`.  I think you could use `adf_client.pipelines.get()` to get the pipeline then replace the `activities` property in it,then update the entire pipeline.

Comment: After getting the pipeline, you could get the value of  `activities`, then replace the value and update the pipeline.

Comment: If you already have some activities already, the `activities` property should be an array. Just append the new activity into it and update the pipeline. Hope i'm clear here.

Comment: Yes thank you for all these informations, I will try the  `adf_client.pipelines.get()` method.

Comment: @Catapultaa You're welcome,any concern,please let me know. Don't forget build the dependency relations between your activities.

Comment: @Catapultaa Hi,any progress? any further help you need?

Comment: Hi I tried `adf_client.pipelines.get`and I am only getting the name of the activity but not the parameters. for Example if I have a Pipeline with only a Wait Activity, the output of `adf_client.pipelines.get`  will be : `{'additional_properties': None, 'id': 'XXXX', 'name': 'test', 'type': 'Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/pipelines', 'etag': 'XXX', 'description': None, 'activities': [<azure.mgmt.datafactory.models.wait_activity_py3.WaitActivity object at XXXX>], 'parameters': None, 'variables': None, 'concurrency': None, 'annotations': None, 'folder': None}` So no information on  waiting time

Comment: @Catapultaa Let me try your code and get the actual value of `activities` property inside for you. Please give me some time.

Comment: @Catapultaa Hi,please see my update code, any concern,please let me know.

Comment: Thank you It works ! the `activities.append()` is exactly the function that I was looking for.

Comment: @Catapultaa Cheers! It's the method for array,not for adf sdk. Anyway,you're welcome.