# Reference of previous activity without naming it

Tags: azure-data-factory

In ADFv2 the expression allows referencing the activity by `@activity('ActivityName')` which can be used to get the output or error. Is it possible to get a reference to the previous activity without knowing or coding the name in the expression?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to get a reference to the previous activity without
>   knowing or coding the name in the expression?

No such feature in ADF as i know. I tried to provide a property here for your reference which you may utilize: `DependsOn`.This property describes the dependencies between components.If multiple activities are caused by previous activity with different statuses,it will be constructed into an array.

[image]

But it is not for usage in the expression,it could be get and set in the sdk. You could refer to some snippet of this case([Python Azure Data Factory Update Pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58417511/python-azure-data-factory-update-pipeline/58423873)) ,especially for `ActivityDependency`.

Comment: Even if there was a way to get DependsOn that isn't going to tell which if the multiple activities caused the current activity to run as DependsOn is an array.

Comment: @amit_g So,does my answer have some values for you?